# Different returns between await method in called function and same directly logged method

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I have for loop which iterates through an array. During each iteration, I want the loop to return the value of the provided webpage and log it to the console.

```
  for (let i = 0; i < jsonObjSplit.length; i++) {    
    console.log(getChangeTicketNum(i));
    const chgNum = getChangeTicketNum(i);
    console.log(getReleaseObj(i, chgNum));
    const release = getReleaseObj(i, chgNum);
    let currentURL = await gotoUrl(release);
    console.log(currentURL);    
  }
```

I call an async function `gotoUrl(release)` which passes an object that contains the url.

```
async function gotoUrl(release) {
    try {
        return await page.goto(release.url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Upon running my code I receive `null` in return.

Example:

```
null
CHG1234567
{
  ticket: 'CHG1234567',
  id: '123',
  url: 'https://exampleurl.net/1234'
}
```

However when I call the method directly in the for loop I receive the correct URL information returned.

Non Null returns:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < jsonObjSplit.length; i++) {    
    
    console.log(getChangeTicketNum(i));
    const chgNum = getChangeTicketNum(i);
    console.log(getReleaseObj(i, chgNum));
    const release = getReleaseObj(i, chgNum);

    console.log(await page.goto(release.url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'}));
  }
```

I am new to aync/await so I am not sure why this is the case.

Comment: Does it really return `null` or is it `undefined`?

Comment: You might get `undefined` if there was an error and the `catch` clause ran. Apart from that, no, they should work identical.

Comment: Please extend your example. Show the output of the iteration of the loop before the `null` occurs and the iteration of the loop when the `null`. Currently the `null` seems to correspond to the previous iteration and the other two outputs to the following iteration.

Comment: The docs say `page.goto either throws an error or returns a main resource response. The only exceptions are navigation to about:blank or navigation to the same URL with a different hash, which would succeed and return null.` which indicates that the URL in the iteration before the `null` occurs has the same URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the function to work 'correctly'. To do this, I called the exact same function a twice. The first time it logs `null` to the console. The second time it returns the url information.

```
//For each item in splunk export file...
for (let i = 0; i < jsonObjSplit.length; i++) {    
    console.log(getChangeTicketNum(i));
    const chgNum = getChangeTicketNum(i);
    console.log(getReleaseObj(i, chgNum));
    const release = getReleaseObj(i, chgNum);
    let currentURL = await gotoXlr(release);
    console.log(currentURL);
    let currentURL2 = await gotoXlr(release);
    console.log(currentURL2);
}
```

Output:

```
null
<ref *1> HTTPResponse {
  _contentPromise: null,
  _headers: {
    date: 'Fri, 30 Jul 2021 13:49:01 GMT',
    'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains',
    'x-xss-protection': '1; mode=block',
    'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'content-type': 'text/html;charset=utf-8',
    'x-frame-options': 'SAMEORIGIN',
    vary: 'Accept-Encoding, User-Agent',
    'content-length': '6270'
  },
  _client: CDPSession {
    eventsMap: Map(29) {
      'Fetch.requestPaused' => [Array],
      'Fetch.authRequired' => [Array],
      'Network.requestWillBeSent' => [Array],
      'Network.requestServedFromCache' => [Array],
      'Network.responseReceived' => [Array],
      'Network.loadingFinished' => [Array],
      'Network.loadingFailed' => [Array],
      'Page.frameAttached' => [Array],
      'Page.frameNavigated' => [Array],
      'Page.navigatedWithinDocument' => [Array],
      'Page.frameDetached' => [Array],
      'Page.frameStoppedLoading' => [Array],
      'Runtime.executionContextCreated' => [Array],
      'Runtime.executionContextDestroyed' => [Array],
      'Runtime.executionContextsCleared' => [Array],
      'Page.lifecycleEvent' => [Array],
      'Target.attachedToTarget' => [Array],
      'Target.detachedFromTarget' => [Array],
      'Page.domContentEventFired' => [Array],
      'Page.loadEventFired' => [Array],
      'Runtime.consoleAPICalled' => [Array],
      'Runtime.bindingCalled' => [Array],
      'Page.javascriptDialogOpening' => [Array],
      'Runtime.exceptionThrown' => [Array],
      'Inspector.targetCrashed' => [Array],
      'Performance.metrics' => [Array],
      'Log.entryAdded' => [Array],
      'Page.fileChooserOpened' => [Array],
      Symbol(CDPSession.Disconnected) => []
    },
ETC...
```

Why this is the case, I am not sure. The page is not loading from an earlier log in function perhaps and has done by the second time the function is called. I know this is not a correct answer but as the async function is correct I decided clarify.